# Access Angular2 app through window loses scope of "this"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-scope, this

I have an Angular2 app that I have exposed certain methods to code running outside of ng2. The problem is that `this` is not the same when called outside of ng2 vs inside.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KZeH1ArvuMTmsBCFjNnY
(watch the console to see whats happening)

In my app component it sets the name to "Angular2" on load. I have the `doSomething` method that does a simple `this.name = "modified angular2 app`. When I call this through `window.myVar.doSomething()` the scope of `this` is not my class, its the object I exposed. How can I access the `name`. I have tried `self = this` in the constructor  and doing `self.name =` which works, but when I bundle and minify for production it fails.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  doSomething(){
    this.name = "modified angular2 app" 
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    window.myVar = {doSomething:this.doSomething}

  }

}
```

In my `index.html` I have added a snippet to call my `doSomething` method.

```
<body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  <script>
    function checkReady() {
      if (window.myVar) {
        console.log("Ready")
        console.log(myVar)
        myVar.doSomething();
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("Not ready")
          checkReady()
        }, 500)
      }
    }
    checkReady()
  </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript has the fat-arrow syntax, you can use that to automatically bind `this` to the class instance:

```
export class App
{
  //...
  doSomething = () => {
    this.name = "modified angular2 app" 
  }
  //...
}
```

Be aware of that this syntax leads to the function `doSomething` is no longer a part of the prototype of `App`.

More info about `this` in typescript/javascript [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#fixes) with pros and cons for different strategies.

Comment: Both solutions work, but I am excepting this as the answer because its the Typescript way of doing it. Working plunker. I had to wrap in NgZone https://plnkr.co/edit/KZeH1ArvuMTmsBCFjNnY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You need to `bind()` your context to the function. That way no matter where it's called from, it will have access to the local variables where it was declared.

```
window.myVar = { doSomething: this.doSomething.bind(this) };
```